# How do I compile Haskell programs using Shake

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I have a Haskell program that I want to compile with GHC, orchestrated by the Shake build system. Which commands should I execute, and under what circumstances should they be rerun?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two approaches to doing the compilation, and two approaches to getting the dependencies. You need to pick one from each set (all 4 combinations make sense), to come up with a combined approach.

**Compilation**

You can either:

- Call `ghc -c` on each file in turn, depending on the `.hs` file and any `.hi` files it transitively imports, generating both a `.hi` and `.o` file. At the end, call `ghc -o` depending on all the `.o` files. For actual code [see this example](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/blob/dd6a446626f67ee053232cef979d5bdcf4a3663a/src/Test/Self.hs).
- *OR* Call `ghc --make` once, depending on all `.hs` files. For actual code [see this example](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/blob/dd6a446626f67ee053232cef979d5bdcf4a3663a/src/Test/SelfMake.hs).

The advantage of `ghc --make` is that it is faster than multiple calls to `ghc -c` since GHC can load each `.hi` file only once, instead of once per command. Typically the speedup is 3x. The disadvantage is parallelism is harder (you can use `-j` to `ghc --make`, but Shake still assumes each action consumes one CPU), and that two `ghc --make` compilations can't both run at the same time if they overlap on any dependencies.

**Dependencies**

You can either:

- Parse the Haskell files to find dependencies recursively. To parse a file you can either look for `import` statements (and perhaps `#include` statements) following a coding convention, or use a library such as [`haskell-src-exts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts). For actual code with a very approximate `import` parser [see this example](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/blob/dd6a446626f67ee053232cef979d5bdcf4a3663a/src/Test/Self.hs).
- *OR* Use the output of `ghc -M` to detect the dependencies, which can be parsed using the Shake helper function [`parseMakefile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake-Util.html#v:parseMakefile). For actual code [see this example](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/blob/75f62cbf285615b4df08c6f3dc5ee7d3bfde961a/src/Test/SelfMake.hs).

The advantage of parsing the Haskell files is that it is possible to have generated Haskell files and it can be much quicker. The advantage of using `ghc -M` is that it is easier to support all GHC features.

Comment: It's great that you post this here, but strictly speaking this doesn't conform with SO policy because only the external code examples answer the question. I think you should embed the crucial rules in the post.

Comment: Thanks @leftaroundabout - I expanded the answers so now the bullet points completely answer the question in enough detail - which is probably way more useful. The code is still linked, but it's not the answer, and it's mostly so people who understand the answer can copy it more easily. I don't want to reproduce the full code in SO since it detracts from the understanding of the answer.